# Create image gallery with vertically centered images of unknown height (css-html)

Tags: html, css, image, image-gallery

I'm using this code:

```
<div id="OptionsPanel">
    <div style="float: left; width:300px; height:auto; background-color:Blue">
        <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
            <div style=" display:inline-block;">
                <img src="Media/1/M113906106291W.jpg" id="ctl06_MediaImage" alt="Option 1" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width:300px; height:auto; background-color:Blue">
        <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
            <div style=" display:inline-block;">
                <img src="Media/1/M113906106292W.jpg" id="ctl07_MediaImage" alt="Option 2" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the code in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EfkxR/

Problem is the floating divs height is not being correctly set with the clearing and thus the images are vertically not centered.

With that code i get:

[image]

And this is what i want: Each row of the gallery show look like this with the height being the one of the tallest image:

[image]

Note: If i set the height of the floating divs to a number, the images are centered correctly, but i don't know that height before i create the divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is using the table-cell display properly and avoid the floating:

```
<div id="OptionsPanel">
<div style=" width:300px; display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle; background-color:Blue;   ">
        <div style=" display:inline-block;">
            <img src="Media/1/M113906234611W.jpg" id="ctl06_MediaImage" alt="Option 1" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style=" width:300px; display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle; background-color:Blue;   ">
        <div style=" display:inline-block;">
            <img src="Media/1/M113906234612W.jpg" id="ctl07_MediaImage" alt="Option 2" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My error was thinking that a clear would make floating divs as tall as their parent.

Using table-cells makes them automatically as tall as the parent div. height:100% or min-height: 100% doesn't work normally.

Answer (score 0):

The `<center>` tag is deprecated. Use `<img align="middle" ...>` instead. Also a good practice is doing stuff like this in CSS.

Comment: I think the problem is not related the the centering, but to the height of the divs. Even if i clear the float, the div on the left stays as tall as its image, as you can see in the first picture.

Comment: So basically you want to vertically center them? But don't want the boarder around them?

Comment: No, i'm just using that border to show that the first floating div is not as tall as the second one.

Comment: Well you can stretch them but they will loose quality.

Comment: Obviously that's not an option ^^

Comment: No, i wanted the second image to be small and centered on the div, not resized as tall as the first one. I didn't explain my problem properly. I've already posted the solution to it.

Comment: I now understand.Use an `inline-block` helper with `height: 100%` and `vertical-align: middle` on both elements. That'll align them from the center of both images so then it'll be the way you wanted it.